# WebApi 2 Call Action From Custom Class in Same Project

Tags: exception, controller, asp.net-web-api2, call, action

I will insert logs from exception handler and i've action for post logs. How can I call my service action properly?

Is creating instance everytime correct?

```
public class CustomExceptionHandler : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var exceptionModel = new System_Logs() { Date = DateTime.Now, Request = actionExecutedContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri, Response = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.ToString()};
        System_LogsController controller = new System_LogsController();
        controller.PostSystem_Logs(exceptionModel);
        base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a logging service class (not a controller class) that will handle logging. If you are using dependency injection, for custom filter attributes use property injection using the `[Dependency]` annotation/decorator to the property. This logging service will be initialized via injection container. You can search in SO for IoC (e.g Unity, autofac, ninject, etc) to help you get started. It's worth knowing this IoC and dependency injection principles as it can apply both on the server side and in the client side(javascript development).

To elaborate on what you currently have. Your code above will look like something like:

```
public class CustomExceptionHandler : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    [Dependency]
    public ILoggingService LoggingService { get; set; }

    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var exceptionModel = new System_Logs() { Date = DateTime.Now, Request = actionExecutedContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri, Response = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.ToString()};
        LoggingService.PostSystemLogs(exceptionModel);
        base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```